# How to call Oracle function with date param via EclipseLink with nativeQuery?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a below code which I am passing four paremeters and second one is Localdate. But it gives me invalid identifer exception, in DB side ORA-00904

```
final EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();

    final LocalDate applicationDate = LocalDate.of(consignmentRequest.getYear(), consignmentRequest.getMonth(), consignmentRequest.getDay());

    final String applicationDateParameter = applicationDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    final String businessPartnerId = consignmentRequest.getBusinessPartnerId();
    final BigDecimal creditAmount = consignmentRequest.getCreditAmount();
    final Integer queryId = consignmentRequest.getEgmQueryId();


    final String FUNCTION_CALL_QUERY = "SELECT FN_VEHICLE_CONTROL(?1,?2,?3,?4) FROM DUAL";


    final BigDecimal value = (BigDecimal) entityManager
            .createNativeQuery(FUNCTION_CALL_QUERY)
            .setParameter(1, businessPartnerId)
            .setParameter(2, applicationDateParameter)
            .setParameter(3, creditAmount)
            .setParameter(4, queryId)
            .getSingleResult();

    entityManager.close();
```

Below also my Oracle function signature,

```js
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GLOBAL.FN_VEHICLE_CONTROL (
   seller      VARCHAR2,
   myDate       DATE,
   amount     NUMBER,
   queryId    NUMBER)
   RETURN NUMBER
```

How can I pass Localdate parameter to query?

Comment: You are calling a stored procedure in the database, not a table select - where are you getting the ORA-00904 from? I'd suggest you check your stored proc code, and verify it can handle the applicationDateParameter string value you are passing in, as the error is likely in your stored proc, not the java side code.

Comment: It works when I call with; SELECT FN_VEHICLE_CONTROL('55501182',TO_DATE('2020-04-06','yyyy-mm-dd'),51695,1015759202) FROM DUAL

Comment: @Chris By the way I post function signature.

Comment: Have you tried passing in a java.sql.Date or Timestamp instead of a string? Otherwise, your method should change to use the "yyyy-MM-dd" string you are passing in directly, or change your SQL you are issuing to use TO_DATE on your parameter - you are using a native query, so the SQL is in your hands.

Comment: I use TO_DATE also passed as Date directly both didnt work.

Comment: Define your question and show what you mean. What did you try, and what result exactly are you getting? If "SELECT FN_VEHICLE_CONTROL('55501182',TO_DATE('2020-04-06','yyyy-mm-dd'),51695,1015759202) FROM DUAL" works, "SELECT FN_VEHICLE_CONTROL(?1,TO_DATE(?2,'yyyy-mm-dd'),?3,?4) FROM DUAL" should too unless you have issues internal to your stored procedure. Only the specific error will help you determine what/where it is going wrong.